# Visual Studio looking in wrong location for web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web site originally designed in Visual Studio 2012. I upgraded to a new machine running 2017. I opened the website in the new VS, upgraded to ASP.net 4.6.1, and then built the project. It built fine. When I F5 to debug however, a configuration error page loads immediately and states:

> "Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring changes to '{correct folder path}\default.aspx'."
>   Source Error:
>
> [No relevant source lines]
>
> Source File: {project root}\default.aspx\web.config

What's weird is it looks like it's trying to find a config file in a sub folder of a web page, which doesn't make any sense to me. The only `web.config` I have is in the root like every other website I've created. No clue on how to resolve this.

If I try to load any other pages I get the exact same error, except it states that page name instead of default.aspx in the path.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but you can try what they did in this SO post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534512/asp-net-is-looking-for-the-web-config-in-the-wrong-place)

Comment: Hi thank you for the comment. Unfortunately, I had already found that document but it didn't help my situation.